# SEO value from subdomain to domain

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain

Does domain get SEO value from the content placed on subdomain? For example, blog.company.com to company.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short..... yes, if you backlink them together but it must have some form of association such as:

1. A brand i.e `banking.tesco.co.uk`, `insurance.tesco.co.uk` the brand being tesco in this example.
2. Similar content i.e `parts.cars.co.uk`, `forum.cars.co.uk` being similar content.
3. Similar niche i.e `wordpress.stackexchange.com`, `webmasters.stackexchange.com` etc.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. :) But I assume content on subdomain gives less value than content on the domain itself?